# Doctrine issue: Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

Tags: symfony, geometry, doctrine, geospatial, symfony4

I followed [this guide](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/advanced-field-value-conversion-using-custom-mapping-types.html) to add `point` type to Doctrine.

This is how I define coordinates field in an Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="point", nullable=true)
 */
private $coordinates;
```

And this is how I'm trying to save an Entity:

```
$obj = new GeoPoint();
$obj->setAddress('Test');
$obj->setCoordinates(new Point(40.7603807, -73.9766831));
$manager->persist($obj);
$manager->flush();
```

My configuration:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            point: Viny\PointType
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        mapping_types:
            point: point
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        quote_strategy: backend_lib.orm.quote_strategy
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

Result DB column definition:

```
`coordinates` point DEFAULT NULL,
```

In result I get:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO `geo_point` (`address`, `coordinates`) VALUES (?, ?)' with params ["Test", "POINT(-73.976683 40.760381)"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1416 Cannot get geometry
>   object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

Final query:

> INSERT INTO `geo_point` (`address`, `coordinates`) VALUES ('Test', 'POINT(-73.976683 40.760381)');

Comment: Add a dump statement to PointType::convertToDatabaseValue and verify that something like POINT(40.7603807, -73.9766831) is being generated.  This will show if the wiring is correct.  Bit strange that new Point() is not throwing a warning for missing constructor arguments but off-topic.

Comment: And I'm pretty sure you want to use types: point: App\...\PointType in your config file.  Otherwise, I don't see how Doctrine will know to use your custom PointType.  https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#doctrine-dbal-configuration

Comment: I have updated error message with the INSERT statement. Also, the output of `PointType::convertToDatabaseValue()` is `string(27) "POINT(-73.976683 40.760381)"` (no comma between coordinates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your posted [doctrine configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#doctrine-dbal-configuration) is wrong.  It should be:

```
#doctrine.yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types: ### Use types instead of mapping_types
            point: App\...\GeoPointType
```

You can tell the mapping is a problem because of your generated sql:

```
INSERT INTO geo_point (address, coordinates) VALUES ('Test', 'POINT(-73.976683 40.760381)');
```

mysql itself does not understand POINT.  It needs to be wrapped in PointFromText.  This wrapping is accomplished via:

```
    // class GeoPointType
    public function convertToDatabaseValueSQL($sqlExpr, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return sprintf('PointFromText(%s)', $sqlExpr);
    }
```

And it is clearly not being called.

[Here is a working example](https://github.com/cerad/geom).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, your answer might be right, but not in my case. Because, an actual reason of this error was my custom `QuoteStrategy::getColumnName()` call which adds quotes: `return $this->quote($class->fieldMappings[$fieldName]['columnName'], $platform);` If this strategy is disabled, SQL is correct: `GeomFromText(?)` <-- function is applied, and with strategy enabled, it's just `?` mark. I don't know why as it's just column name, not a value

Comment: Well okay.  I am not doing any custom quoting but I did try your mapping_types config and all I got was a DBAL exception: 'Type to be overwritten point does not exist.'  I suspect you may have some other doctrine bundles installed or something.  So it goes.

Comment: I have switched to `CrEOF/doctrine2-spatial` so my config is right already and similar issue was happening.  This is the file: https://gist.github.com/lngphp/a6e9a5de1287604ad4ffb9d25c1abcb2

Comment: This is how it's enabled: https://gist.github.com/lngphp/3857a8c3000a9789c596ab250874cd1f